# How to install glibc?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I have installed glibc into /usr/local/glibc and tested if it is installed properly as well using the following link

http://www.naink.net/2013/197/

What i would like to know is how do i link this new library so that i can install applications that require this library.

Note: I am using raspbian ver 2013-12-20

Comment: I believe any projects that require this library should work once you reboot, though I can't be certain. That tutorial you linked to doesn't give any instructions regarding linking, so I believe it should work.

Comment: Well yes it is supposed to but it aint, I am new to this so i was hoping that someone could help me in linking the library, by default it goes about using the old one.